# Syntax for loop ManagedObject insertion in swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

On the process of exploring Core Data with Swift I have the following function working, as a test:

```
func insertObject (entityName:String) {
    var newItem = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName(entityName, inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext!) as! EventList
    let now = NSDate()
    newItem.date = now
    newItem.eventDescription = “Whatever Anniversary"
}
```

This seems to work, but to make my function more useful, I want to pass it a dictionnary describing the object I intend to insert.
Something like the following:

```
func insertObject (entityName:String,dico:NSDictionary) {
    var newItem = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName(entityName, inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext!) as! EventList
    for (key, value) in dico {
        println("\(key) : \(value)")
        newItem.key = value
    }
}
```

Here comes the problem, this line is wrong:

```
    newItem.key = value
```

What is the proper syntax to use?

This line shows me that the looping part works fine:

```
    println("\(key) : \(value)")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Key-Value coding for managed objects:

```
func insertObject (entityName:String, dico: [String : NSObject]) {
    let newItem = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName(entityName, inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext!) as! EventList
    for (key, value) in dico {
        newItem.setValue(value, forKey: key)
    }
}
```

which can be shortened to

```
func insertObject (entityName:String, dico: [String : NSObject]) {
    let newItem = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName(entityName, inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext!) as! EventList
    newItem.setValuesForKeysWithDictionary(dico)
}
```

The problem with this general approach is that it will crash at
runtime if the dictionary contains keys which are not properties
of the entity, or if the data type does not match.

Comment: Thanks, it works. Except that instead of "newItem.setValue(value, forKey: key)" I have to use "newItem.setValue(value, forKey: key as! String)" to avoid a compile error.

Comment: I will try the shortened syntax later.

Comment: @Michel: Note that I changed the type of the "dico" parameter to `[String : NSObject]`, then you don't have to cast the key.